# Question on ColumnTransformer OneHotEncoder VS mode_onehot_pipe

Tags: scikit-learn

I would like to ask what's the different between  `OneHotEncoder` and `mode_onehot_pipe`

```
mode_onehot_pipe = Pipeline([
    ('encoder', SimpleImputer(strategy = 'most_frequent')),
    ('one hot encoder', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown = 'ignore'))])

transformer = ColumnTransformer([
('one hot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown = 'ignore'), ['Gender', 'Age', 'Working_Status', 'Annual_Income', 'Visit_Duration', 'Spending_Time', 'Outlet_Location', 'Member_Card', 'Average_Spending']),
('mode_onehot_pipe', mode_onehot_pipe, ['Visit_Plan'])], remainder = 'passthrough')
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is `mode_onehot_pipe`? Could you add the corresponding code as it is not a `scikit-learn` standard.

Comment: I refer to the code in the link above https://www.kaggle.com/aditiani/starbucks-customers-accuracy/notebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference between the two is the way they handle `nan` values.

`mode_onehot_pipe` will replace `nan` by the most frequent value  according to the `SimpleImputer` configuration while `OneHotEncoder` will create a category for `nan` values.

If you pass the same feature, you will end up with one extra feature for the `OneHotEncoder` which will represents the `nan` values.